# How to run shp2pgsql in python without reporting every row loaded?

Tags: python, postgis, postgresql, shp2pgsql

I'm running shp2pgsql in python with a simple script, which works just fine:

```
import os
import subprocess

cmd = 'shp2pgsql -s 4326 ../data/shp/statistical_neighborhoods.shp temp_table | psql -h hostname -d databasename -U username'

subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
```

The problem is, for every record loaded, there is a message reported:

```
INSERT 0 1
```

That message is reported for the 78 records in the neighborhoods layer in the example above, but for a file with 280,000 records (address point file from the City, or Parcels layer), that would be a very unnecessary amount of messages.

Is this problem coming from shp2pgsql, or is it a result of the subprocess.call() function?

Comment: You could try to use the -q operator (quiet) with the psql command.

Comment: @Matte that did it - please put that in as an answer! That's not in the cheatsheet...!  http://www.bostongis.com/pgsql2shp_shp2pgsql_quickguide_20.bqg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid a message from subprocess.call when psql writes its informations to stdout you can simply tell psql to not write any information. The operator is -q or --quiet as taken from the psql manual.

Comment: Ah OK I was trying to find this in the shp2pgsql documentation... Thanks again!